# Rails Devise - How to add more data to current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Suppose I have a User model

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
end
```

with attributes like: name, username, access

access is an enum that tells me if the user is "staff" or "customer"

To get the name and username of the logged in user, I can do:

```
current_user.name
current_user.username
```

And suppose I have a Staff model

**staff.rb**

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

with attributes like: salary, phone_number

And I also have a Customer model

**customer.rb**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

with attributes like: address, phone_number

---

I want to be able to call this on my staff's controller:

```
current_user.staff.salary
```

And this on my customer's controller:

```
current_user.customer.address
```

---

**WHAT I TRIED SO FAR**

I overwrote sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  super
  model_name = current_user.access.capitalize.constantize
  spec = model_name.where(user_id: current_user.id).take
  session[:spec] = spec
end
```

So I'm able to access it via session[:spec], but not via current_user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to begin with, your User model should reference the staff or customer, even if they are to stay blank

```
class User

  has_one :staff
  has_one :address
```

Just by doing this, you should be able to use `current_user.customer.address`. However...

I suggest you add some convenient methods in ApplicationController or a module that you include

```
def staff_signed_in?
  @staff_signed_in ||= (user_signed_in? and current_user.access == :staff)
end

def current_staff
  @current_staff ||= (current_user.staff if staff_logged_in?)
end

# same for customer
# Note that I use instance variables so any database queries are executed only once !
```

Then you can simply call

```
<% if customer_signed_in? %>
  <h2>Logged in as customer</h2>
  <p>Address : <%= current_customer.address %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT : about your concerns concerning database hits

You gave the example of current_user.customer.cart.products

This is indeed quite a nested association. My suggestion above already reduces it by one level (ie current_customer == current_user.customer). Then you have to go through carts to reach products... it isn't so bad in my opinion. 
If you need to call that often (current_customercustomer.cart) you can override the current_customer for a given controller and eager load the resources you know you will use use.

```
def UserShopController < ApplicationController
# Let's assume current_customer is defined in ApplicationController like I showed above
# UserShopController always uses the customer cart, so let's load it right at the beginning
...

private
    # Override with eager loading
    def current_customer
      @current_customer ||= (current_user.customer.includes(:cart) if customer_logged_in?)
    end
```

Comment: You showed me how I can access current_customer.address. I haven't tried yet. Is there any way to access like current_user.customer.address?

Comment: As long as you add the `has_one` statements, `current_user.customer.address` should also work

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I'm wondering, though, why did you make that suggestion. Maybe you're talking about a case where the views are shared?

Comment: I'm using a similar system where a user can be logged in as admin, contractor, client, all at the same time. Then for example, in my view I want to show only the "admin" menu to the admin, so I use a lot helpers like `administrator_signed_in?` instead of `user_signed_in? and user.administrator?`, just like in the last example I gave.

Comment: I wonder if it hurts performance if we start making too many "joins"

Comment: Note that my code hits the database only once, because then the instance variables are set, and if calling `customer_signed_in?` once more, it will directly look at the object in memory. Not sure about which "join" you are reffering to ?

Comment: In rails console, every time I do current_user.something it shows a query that it makes, with the SQL. For example: current_user.customer.cart.products, to get the products that is on the logged customer's cart, it would join the tables user with customer, then customer with cart, then cart with product, to retrive the products

Comment: See my edit, also you can google "eager loading in rails", you should find interesting results.

Comment: That's a very complete answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

add `has_one :customer` to your user.rb

Your user model should be like below to accessing related model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :customer
end
```